# How can I have different text in the footer on every page of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there an easy way to add different text in footer on every page of a word document?

Comment: If it's a different footer on every page then it's not really a footer in the traditional sense. What is it that you're putting in it?

Comment: Correct.
I was trying to put some quotations in the footer.
Different quote for each page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bumped into the same issue myself. Here's the [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071114135146AAONwr2) post on the subject. The selected answer from that post recommends maintaining a separate section for each page:

> Each header and footer is "linked" for
>   each section. So if you make each page
>   a separate "section" (i.e., section
>   break instead of a page break), then
>   you can unlink the footers and place a
>   different footer for each section.
>
> This is the only way I know that will
>   allow the different footer for each
>   page.

That's a terrible hassle in my opinion, so I decided to waive having different footers on each page. Sadly I'm not aware of any alternative neat solution in Microsoft Word. This is definitely a feature request: Microsoft - please add a checkbox for "Different Footer on Every Page".

Answer (score 6):

> Is there an easy way …

An *easy* way?  Apparently not; in 3½ years, nobody has found one. 
One rather ugly approach is to use `IF` fields.  For example,

```
{ IF { PAGE } = 1 "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,"
{ IF { PAGE } = 2 "Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore —"
{ IF { PAGE } = 3 "While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,"
                  "As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door." } } }
```

will display the first four lines of *The Raven* on pages 1-4.  Here’s a (slightly hairy) procedure that will let you enter the above to play with it (and, of course, you can change the text).

1. Edit the footer.

   Copy the following text:

   ```
   IF PAGE = 1 "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,"
   IF PAGE = 2 "Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore —"
   IF PAGE = 3 "While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,"
               "As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door."
   ```

   into the footer.

   Select each of the words and phrases that appears in braces in the first code block (sequentially) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.  A possible order:

   - Each occurrence of `PAGE` (one at a time).

     From (the beginning of) the third `IF` through the very end
         (after `door."`).

     From (the beginning of) the second `IF` through the very end.

     From (the beginning of) the first `IF` through the very end.

   This will convert each of those strings to a field, and, consequently,
   add the `{` and `}` to the display.

   Right-click on the first `IF` and select “Toggle Field Codes”.

   Close the footer.

## Explanation

<sup>(In case any is needed)</sup>

Basically, this is Microsoft Word’s implementation of the `IF`-`THEN`-`ELSE` construct
that is common in programming languages, as in

```
IF  Todays’s date is 1
THEN
    Today is Monday
ELSE IF  Todays’s date is 2
THEN
    Today is Tuesday
ELSE IF  Todays’s date is 3
THEN
    Today is Wednesday
ELSE
    Here comes the weekend!
END IF
```

Microsoft Excel has an

> `IF(` *Logical_test* **`,`** *Value_if_true* **`,`** *Value_if_false* `)`

function that works similarly.  Generally, they can all be nested.

Comment: this is a better answer than the accepted one as using section breaks  affects other features of the page

Comment: Thanks for the praise. In the OP’s defense, he asked this question in September 2009 and accepted the answer in July 2010.  I didn’t post my answer until April 2013, so, for all we know, he hasn’t even seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Some hint found [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33055271/different-headerfooter-o.aspx) :

> I am not sure I know enough about your
>   document to come up with a solution.
>   However, I am wondering whether you
>   could use STYLEREF fields in the
>   header. A STYLEREF field can pick up
>   the contents of text formatted with a
>   specific style. If the information you
>   need to show to the header is found
>   directly on the page, you could format
>   the text with a special style made for
>   that purpose and make the STYLEREF
>   field pick up the text.
>
> A STYLEREF field inserted in a header
>   (or footer) prints the first (or last)
>   text formatted with the specified
>   style on the current page. The field
>   is automatically updated whenever you
>   change the text in the document. If no
>   text formatted with the style in
>   question is found on a page, the
>   STYLEREF field repeats the same text
>   on all subsequent pages until another
>   occurrence of the specified style is
>   found.
>
> For further details about the STYLEREF
>   field, search for "Field codes:
>   StyleRef field" in the online help
>   of Word. See also the following two articles :
>   [Repeating form field data in a header/footer](http://sbarnhill.mvps.org/WordFAQs/StyleRef.htm#FormField) 
>   [Repeating Data (or populating fields)](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Repeating_Data.htm).

Comment: I believe that this is, in principle, the best answer listed here.  But I believe that it’s unusable due to lack of detail.  Would you please try to distill the procedure into something brief and post it here?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a very easy way to do this. Before you begin writing your document you need to go to the Reference tab. At the tab there will be  "insert footnote" and "insert endnote" buttons.

At the bottom of the section where those buttons are located there is a small arrow you can click to open up the advanced settings for footnotes. Click the bubble for footnote, and make sure all the settings are to your liking.

Click "Apply" then "OK"

From now on, whenever you want to insert a footnote for citations or whatever you want, put your period for the end of the sentence, go to the insert tab, click "Insert Footnote," type your footnote, double click your document and continue writing. This way, all footnotes will be independent of one another and you won't have to deal with footnotes being copied over on every page.

Comment: The question is about ***page footers***, not footnotes.  This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just click on the part of the text which is where the footnote relates to and click on the references tab and then add footnote it places a number in the text and in the footer for you to type your additional information and will only display on that page.

Comment: The question is about ***page footers***, not footnotes.  This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

> First of All insert Section Break on
>   every page which you want to make
>   different then click on Footer Section
>   you'll see in ur footer right section
>   same as previous now click on tool bar
>   Header & Footer Link to Previous again
>   now "same as previous will be
>   disappear"

[Source](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/1389592)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way of doing this in Word 2010:

1. Double click in the footer you want to change.
2. On the “Header & Footer Tools” / “Design” tab, click the “Link to Previous” button (located in the “Navigation” panel, beneath the “Previous Section” and “Next Section” buttons).
3. That's it! Now just change the text, and it won't be linked to the previous footer.

Comment: This is not a separate answer.  This is a detail of the very first answer (posted Sep 26, 2009 by Roee Adler) that got left out.  This does no good (in fact, it doesn’t do anything) unless the document is already broken down into tiny sections.