# find field references/dependencies in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a ms word file in front of me with ''tons'' of fields. Now im trying to figure out what field is dependent on what other field... or is not referred to at all. Stupid comparison: in excel you put in cell B5 "=A1". If i type something in A1, B5 changes. When i select cell B5 i can see =A1 so B5's reference is A1. Now, how can i check something like that in word's fields? 
thanks you all
best regards,
Erik

Comment: Can you give an example of how one field in a Word document might depend on another?

Comment: Ho scott, create e.g. 2 fields. Name them both e.g. scott. Enter in your first field hello. Press crtl+ A. Press F9. The second field will contain "hello" too now. Dont know if its called dependecy, but thats what i mean with dependency, haha.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your example, and I cannot get the second field to change to the value entered into the first one.   I assume that you’re describing a real phenomenon — actual behavior that you have observed — and that I’m doing it wrong.   I’m doing it wrong because I can’t read your mind, and you have not provided a sufficiently clear or detailed description of what you’re talking about for me to understand.   Please try again.   I estimate that 42 words might be just about the right level of detail. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (Note that, after 2½ days (60 hours), my comment has been the only response that you have gotten, and my comment has gotten up voted (and your question has not).  Your chances of getting an answer go up astronomically if people can understand your question.)

Comment: P.S. OK, I have now (after a few more minutes) reproduced something similar to what you described.  But, since it’s not *exactly* what you described, I don’t know whether it is what you are thinking and talking about.  So my above comments (asking you to clarify your question) stand. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.P.S. In case you believe that I’m just wasting your time, let me show you [How can I have different text in the footer on every page of a Word document?](https://superuser.com/q/47345/150988#578165) as evidence that I know a little bit about fields in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Hi Scott, thx a lot! the problem was as i know now that Stylerefs en TOC for example werent clear to me as being fields (not greyed out). if you insert a field and click on type styleref, a field is generated, but not greyed out. so i missed it as being a field! cheers for all your efforts!!!

Comment: If your question wasn’t just a misunderstanding and you have solved your problem (in a non-trivial way), please post your solution in the “Your Answer” box.  You might earn some reputation points, and you might help somebody else who has the same question in the future.  Of course, it will be hard for somebody else to know whether they have the same question if you don’t [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.